# LABjs - erro ao carregar scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugin

Por favor não me mostrem o link da documentação http://labjs.com/documentation.php ou exemplos retirados de lá porque isso eu já li, e sinceramente não entendi o porque o meu código da erro "*de vez em quando*" ou seja, a pagina carrega umas três vezes aproximadamente e depois uma da erro.

Então estou crendo que o problema é o assincronismo, já mexi um monte na ordem dos scripts, colocando .wait em tudo, só em alguns e por fim não deu em nada segue o último teste:

```
$LAB            
.script('../js/date.js')                                        // NAO TEM DEPENDENCIA
.script('../js/plugin/jquery.insc.estadual.js')                 // NAO TEM DEPENDENCIA            
.script('../js/node/socket.io.js').wait()                       // NAO TEM DEPENDENCIA
.script('../js/js_1.9/jquery-1.8.2.js').wait()                  // NAO TEM DEPENDENCIA
.script('../js/jquery.shortcuts.min.js')                        // DEPENDE DE JQUERY
.script('../js/jquery.meiomask.js')                             // DEPENDE DE JQUERY
.script('../lib/jquery.validate.js')                            // DEPENDE DE JQUERY
.script('../js/js_1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js').wait()    // DEPENDE DE JQUERY                        
.script('../js/dataBr.js')                                      // DEPENDE DE JQUERY E JQUERY-UI
.script('../js/plugin/jquery.zoomooz.js')                       // DEPENDE DE JQUERY E JQUERY-UI                        
.script('../js/custom_jquery.js?nocache='+Math.random())        // DEPENDE DE JQUERY E JQUERY-UI                            
.script('../js/principal.js?nocache='+Math.random());           // DEPENDE DE JQUERY , JQUERY-UI E SOCKET.IO
```

Os erros que aparecem esporadicamente são:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

as vezes só esses:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

as vezes só um:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

To mais perdido que cedo em tiroteio, alguém pode me dar me ajudar ?

Comment: não sou um especialista em `php` e muito menos em `labjs`, mas pelo o que entendi do funcionamento dele, você não precisa de um `wait()` para o `socket.io` e o `jquery.insc.estadual` depende do jquery, portanto deve vir depois dele, por fim acredito que é necessario um `wait()` antes do `principal.js`, como neste [codebin](http://codebin.org/view/9118f256)

Comment: @TobyMosque pensou que jquery.insc.estadual tenha dependencia por causa do nome do arquivo, mas já abri o arquivo e ele é javascript puro, eu que coloquei o nome nele errado, o socket.io eu coloquei ele no `wait` porque o principal.js depende dele

Comment: pelo o que entendi do `labjs`, ele irá baixar de forma assincrona os arquivos, o `wait()` fará que ele espere todos os scripts baixarem e serem executados antes de continuar, então colocando o `wait()` apos do `jquery.js`, fará que else espere à conclusão do `date.js`, `insc.estadual.js`, `socket.io.js` e o `jquery.js`, então não há a necessidade de por um `wait()` para o `socket.io`. realmente o nome do `insc.estadual.js` me fez pensar que ele dependia do `jquery.js`.

Comment: Mas ainda acredito que o `principal.js` faça algum uso do `dataBr.js`, `zoomooz.js` ou `custom_jquery.js`, por isto pedi para colocar um `wait()` apos o `custom_jquery.js`

Comment: tentei mas não resolveu

Comment: o problema deve ser conflito de scripts, algum script está conflitando com outros, e quando esse carrega mais rápido do que o outro, dá esse erro. Tente mudar a ordem deles e faça testes. Acredito que o jquery deve sempre ficar no topo. Eu não confiaria nesse `.wait() `

Comment: @IvanFerrer a idéia toda é baseada na confiança desse .wait() rsrsrsr, o jquery em cima como primeiro foi minha primeira tentativa, acabei colocando outros em cima dele para separar o que não tem dependencia, mas obrigado mesmo assim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom vou colocar aqui a solução, para que outros não precisem perder tempo quando acontecer isso, bem coisas estranhas acontecem nessa vida, e isso foi um dos casos estranhos, talvez alguém saiba o por que dessas coisas, eu simplesmente vou desvia-las por não entender muito bem.

Primeiramente esse teste foi feito com o **firebug** no **firefox**, gosto muito e sempre usei e provavelmente sempre vou usa-lo, deixando o achismo de lado vamos adiante, com o código do mesmo jeito me deu na cabeça de testar com o **chrome** com o as *ferramentas de desenvolvedor* padrão, para minha surpresa todas as repetidas vezes que testei foram bem sucedidas.

Logo voltando para o *firefox* peguei a *ferramenta de desenvolvedor* padrão e testei novamente e deu tudo certo também, mas, antes de postar minha resposta e colocar toda a culpa no *firebug* fiz outros testes, e para minha surpresa o problema poderia ser apresentado em ambos navegadores com quaisquer ferramenta que estivesse ligado todas as opções de monitoramento.

Ou seja quando habilitado o **console, script, rede e cookie** com todas as opções disponíveis gerava esse erro, inclusive com esses monitores ligados o tempo para abrir a pagina era bem maior, sem esses monitores ligados fica em torno dos 400ms, com os monitores ligados chegava a dar 3 segs para carregar e muitas das vezes ocorriram esses erros, agora o porque disso talvez seja até pertinente em outra pergunta